# R reshaping melted data.table with list column

Tags: r, data.table, bigdata, reshape

I have a large (millions of rows) melted `data.table` with the usual `melt`-style unrolling in the `variable` and `value` columns. I need to cast the table in wide form (rolling the variables up). The problem is that the data table also has a list column called `data`, which I need to preserve. This makes it impossible to use `reshape2` because `dcast` cannot deal with non-atomic columns. Therefore, I need to do the rolling up myself.

The answer from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968579/fast-melted-data-table-operations) about working with melted data tables does not apply here because of the list column.

I am not satisfied with the solution I've come up with. I'm looking for suggestions for a simpler/faster implementation.

```
x <- LETTERS[1:3]
dt <- data.table(
  x=rep(x, each=2),
  y='d',
  data=list(list(), list(), list(), list(), list(), list()),
  variable=rep(c('var.1', 'var.2'), 3),
  value=seq(1,6)
  )

# Column template set up
list_template <- Reduce(
  function(l, col) { l[[col]] <- col; l }, 
  unique(dt$variable),
  list())

# Expression set up
q <- substitute({
  l <- lapply(
    list_template, 
    function(col) .SD[variable==as.character(col)]$value)
  l$data = .SD[1,]$data
  l
}, list(list_template=list_template))

# Roll up
dt[, eval(q), by=list(x, y)]

   x y var.1 var.2   data
1: A d     1     2 <list>
2: B d     3     4 <list>
3: C d     5     6 <list>
```

Comment: @Arun done; I had posted while I was simplifying the code and coming up with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

This old question piqued my curiosity as `data.table` has been improved sigificantly since 2013.

However, even with `data.table` version 1.11.4

```
dcast(dt, x + y + data ~ variable)
```

still returns an error

> Columns specified in formula can not be of type list

The workaround follows the general outline of [jonsedar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16607887/3817004) :

1. Reshape the non-list columns from long to wide format
2. Aggregate the list column `data` grouped by `x` and `y`
3. Join the two partial results on `x` and `y`

but uses the features of the actual `data.table` syntax, e.g., the `on` parameter:

```
dcast(dt, x + y ~ variable)[
  dt[, .(data = .(first(data))), by = .(x, y)], on = .(x, y)]
```

> ```
>    x y var.1 var.2   data
> 1: A d     1     2 <list>
> 2: B d     3     4 <list>
> 3: C d     5     6 <list>
> ```

The list column `data` is aggregated by taking the first element. This is in line with OP's code line

```
l$data = .SD[1,]$data
```

which also picks the first element.

Comment: Or (essentially the same) ... `xdt = dt[, .SD[1L], by=.(x, y), .SDcols="data"]; mdt = dt[, .(x, variable, value)]; merge(xdt, dcast(mdt, x ~ variable), by="x")` (I think OP's input and output tables are both malformed and they should split it across multiple tables.)

Answer (score 1):

I have somewhat cheating method that might do the trick - importantly, I assume that each x,y,list combination is unique! If not, please disregard.

I'm going to create two separate datatables, the first which is dcasted without the data list objects, and the second which has only the unique data list objects and a key. Then just merge them together to get the desired result.

```
require(data.table)
require(stringr)
require(reshape2)

x <- LETTERS[1:3]
dt <- data.table(
  x=rep(x, each=2),
  y='d',
  data=list(list("a","b"), list("c","d")),
  variable=rep(c('var.1', 'var.2'), 3),
  value=seq(1,6)
  )


# First create the dcasted datatable without the pesky list objects:
dt_nolist <- dt[,list(x,y,variable,value)]
dt_dcast <- data.table(dcast(dt_nolist,x+y~variable,value.var="value")
                       ,key=c("x","y"))


# Second: create a datatable with only unique "groups" of x,y, list
dt_list <- dt[,list(x,y,data)]

# Rows are duplicated so I'd like to use unique() to get rid of them, but
# unique() doesn't work when there's list objects in the data.table.
# Instead so I cheat by applying a value to each row within an x,y "group" 
# that is unique within EACH group, but present within EVERY group.
# Then just simply subselect based on that unique value.
# I've chosen rank(), but no doubt there's other options

dt_list <- dt_list[,rank:=rank(str_c(x,y),ties.method="first"),by=str_c(x,y)]

# now keep only one row per x,y "group"
dt_list <- dt_list[rank==1]
setkeyv(dt_list,c("x","y"))

# drop the rank since we no longer need it
dt_list[,rank:=NULL]

# Finally just merge back together
dt_final <- merge(dt_dcast,dt_list)
```